# How can I override a module with a custom module?

Tags: forms, 9

The [Bee](https://www.drupal.org/project/bee) module has a `addReservationFrom` form class. I would like to override it.

I copied `addReservationFrom` to `MyaddReservationForm` and made the necessary modifications. This works as excepted, but `MyaddReservationForm` is in the original module and I would like to move the changes into a custom module.

I created a custom module, but when I move `MyaddReservationForm` to *custom/my_reservations/src/Form*, `MyReservationsForm` is not used.

#### info.yml

```yml
name: my reservations
type: module
description: overrides bee reservation
package: custom
core_version_requirement: ^9 || ^10
dependencies:
  - bee
  - bat:bat_booking
  - bat:bat_event_series
  - bat:bat_event_ui
  - office_hours:office_hours
```

#### routing.yml

```yml
my_reservations.my_reservations:
  path: '/my-reservations/my-reservations'
  defaults:
    _title: 'My reservations'
    _form: 'Drupal\my_reservations\Form\MyReservationsForm'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\bee\Controller\MyBeeController::addReservationTitle'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### reservationsForm

```php
namespace Drupal\my_reservations\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\bat_event_series\Entity\EventSeries;
use Drupal\commerce_cart\CartManagerInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_cart\CartProviderInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\office_hours\OfficeHoursDateHelper;
use RRule\RRule;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


/**
 * Provides a My reservations form.
 */
class MyReservationsForm extends FormBase {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: If this is a new route you need to alter the existing route and change the _form property. Alternatively, do a form alter.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal you have two options that are preferable to copying the file across as you've done. Drupal is OOP, and also contains alter hooks, which are meant to prevent code from being copied.

The common way to do what you are doing is to use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9.3.x), to massage the form render array and alter it to make the form you want. This is good for minor changes. For major changes, you can extend the form using OOP principles, then `[replace the form used at the route][1]`.

Comment: Due to major changes I prefer to extend the form using OOP principles. I don't know how to do this exactly.  Therefore I will create a new question, thnx